# Octave can't find function handle

Tags: matlab, octave

I use Octave to run the [selective search](https://github.com/sergeyk/selective_search_ijcv_with_python) code, it gives me this error:

`error: @SSSimColourTextureSizeFillOrig: no function and no method found`.

The code which arises this error is:

```
simFunctionHandles = {@SSSimColourTextureSizeFillOrig, @SSSimTextureSizeFill, @SSSimBoxFillOrig, @SSSimSize};
```

But this code can successfully run on MATLAB, so I supposed there is some bugs in Octave or it doesn't support function handle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Octave has absolutely no problems with function handles.  What the exact problem in your case is, is the format of the files.

If you look at the Github repo that is linked in your post, the functions you are referring to are MATLAB [P-Code files](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcode.html).  These are obfuscated MATLAB files which can only be run in MATLAB.  The purpose of P-Code files is to take the original source code and sort of hide what the original source was so you can't take the original source and modify it for your own use.  That being said, you have no choice but to use this function for your purposes and you can't modify its behaviour.

However, Octave does not have this kind of obfuscation support and so naturally it can't reconstruct what the original code was for you to run.

Check out this Octave thread for more details:  http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Matlab-p-files-td1627334.html

.... so basically, you're [SOL](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=SOL).  You can only run those functions in MATLAB.  However, you may have some luck by contacting the original author and obtaining the original `.m` files, but the fact that these are P-Code files is probably because there are some methods and techniques that the author doesn't want to share, but needs to distribute this code in such a way that the rest of the system will work.

Comment: No problem. Sorry if this wasn't the answer you were looking for!

Answer (score 1):

For those who end up here, one possibility is that you are calling the function before it is defined. For example, the below code

```
f = @computeSquare;
a = 4;
b = f(a);

function y = computeSquare(x)
    y = x.^2;
end
```

from [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html), will cause the error:

```
error: invalid function handle, unable to find function for @computeSquare
error: called from
    test at line 3 column 3
```

The only thing you have to do is to move the function definition above the place you have called it:

```
function y = computeSquare(x)
    y = x.^2;
end

f = @computeSquare;
a = 4;
b = f(a);
```

Comment: Looking forward to seeing more people on [Octave's Discord channel](https://mail.gnu.org/archive/html/help-octave/2020-09/msg00010.html).